# Visual Studio Community 2017: How do i publish apps to the Microsoft Store?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have made a simple program (not a Windows **APP**, just a normal program), and would like to publish that on the Microsoft Store. My question is: how do i do that? And is it possible to do that in the Visual Studio Community edition? It's coded in Visual Basic. Thank's already! Sorry if i was unclear!

Answer (score 0):

If your program is not a VB UWP project, you could use [desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) to convert your app to UWP app. Please make sure that you can create the package correctly and the app must meet the [App package requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements), then you can follow the steps to submit your app to the Microsoft.
For more information,you can read in official document: [App submissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions).